# Represent options from a checkbox in a use case description

Tags: uml, use-case

The user has a checkbox where he can check as many options as he wants (or none at all) and click proceed. How can I represent this in a use case description? I can't figure it out.

Comment: this is not a use-case thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use cases should be unaware of the details of the user interface. The point of use cases is to give a high level overview of what the system does or will do.